# Is it possible to approximate some PDE semigroups by explicit methods?

Tags: linear-pde

I'm concerned with numerical methods for the approximation of semigroup associated to following Cauchy problems (which typically involves unbounded operators):
$$
\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{du}{dt} + Au  =  0 \\
\\
 u(0) = u_0 
\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
When $A$ is an $M$-accretive operator it is known [1] that, a solution $u(t)$ can be given by an exponential formula :
$$
u(t) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\left(I + \frac{t}{n}\right)^{-1}\right]^n u_0 \label{2}\tag{2}
$$
which can be seen as an implicit Euler discretization scheme in time for the Cauchy problem \eqref{1}.

**Question**:
Is it possible for some operators $A$ (typically a laplacian) to approximate the semigroup using an explicit scheme such as
$$
U_{k+1} = U_k + hAU_k\;?\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
**Reference**

[1] Haïm Brezis "Analyse fonctionnelle et applications", Masson et Cie.